# How to exclude two rows if have same value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that extract some alarm from table.

I want to extract the alarm with name "alarm1" for 
"NODE_A" only if there isn't "alarm_2" for the same "NODE_A"

Thanks in advance!

```
NODE_ID | PORT_ID | ALARM_ID | CREATION_TIME   

NODE_A  | PORT_A  | ALARM_1  | CREATION_1

NODE_B  | PORT_B  | ALARM_3  | CREATION_2

NODE_A  | PORT_A  | ALARM_2  | CREATION_1

NODE_C  | PORT_C  | ALARM_1  | CREATION_4

NODE_C  | PORT_C  | ALARM_2  | CREATION_4



select  NODE_ID,
        PORT_ID,
    ALARM_ID,
        CREATION_TIME

from    TABLE

where   ALARM_ID='ALARM_1' OR ALARM_ID='ALARM_2' OR ALARM_ID='ALARM_3' AND
        CONCAT(NODE_ID, CREATION_TIME) <> CONCAT(NODE_ID, CREATION_TIME)
```

the results that I want is:

```
NODE_ID | PORT_ID | ALARM_ID | CREATION_TIME   


NODE_B  | PORT_B  | ALARM_3  | CREATION_2
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: What does the table look like? What SQL have you tired? What results do you want? This question really doesn’t lead anywhere …

Comment: So do you want output where same node doesn't have `alarm1` and `alarm2` both? Becuase in your sample only `node_b` is satisfying that condition

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tuple with not in a count > 1

```
  select  NODE_ID,
          PORT_ID,
          ALARM_ID,
          CREATION_TIME
  from  TABLE
  where  NODE_ID   not in ( select NODE_ID
                            FROM TABLE
                            GROUP BY NODE_ID
                            having count(*) > 1)
```

Or use a join eg:

```
  select  NODE_ID,
          PORT_ID,
          ALARM_ID,
          CREATION_TIME
  from  TABLE 
  inner join (
      select NODE_ID,count(*) 
      FROM TABLE
      GROUP BY NODE_ID
      having count(*) = 1)
    ) t1 on t1.NODE_ID = TABLE.NODE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the results include also the alarm that I want to exclude. If I have the alarm_2 and alarm_1 for the same NODE I want to exclude both rows.

Comment: The result is the same, the rows with alarm_1 remain, it not show only the row with the alarm_2.

Comment: @NicolòGerosa - It would be whole lot easier if you add some more rows in your sample data and show us your expected output based on that.

Comment: @Utsav I modified the question with the results that I want. Thanks

Comment: seems strange becase the suquery should retunr the NODE with more then a rows so the not in should exclude NODE_A and NODE_C ... check the subquery please

Comment: @scaisEdge I modified my question adding in the where the alarm that I want to show. With this difference the results with your subquery is not correct. It show also the alarm that I want to exclude

Comment: The subselect return one row for NODE_A, one row for NODE_B and one row for NODE_C.

Comment: The result is the same as the previous. The query return also the row that I want to exclude

Comment: then the sample that you have provided in your question is not the same you are using for test and you have also node with more then a row...

Comment: Yes is the same. I want to extract some alarm from a table and if the same node have two different alarm (alarm_1 and alarm_2) the query don't show me the rows.

Comment: impossible  ... based  on data sample ... check better

Answer (score 0):

Use `count` combined with `case`:

```
select node_id, port_id, alarm_id, creation_time 
  from (select t.*, 
               count(case when alarm_id = 'ALARM_2' then 1 end) 
                     over (partition by node_id, creation_time) cnt
          from t )
  where cnt = 0
```

Test:

```
with t (NODE_ID, PORT_ID, ALARM_ID, CREATION_TIME) as (
     select 'NODE_A', 'PORT_A', 'ALARM_1', 'CREATION_1' from dual union all
     select 'NODE_B', 'PORT_B', 'ALARM_3', 'CREATION_2' from dual union all
     select 'NODE_A', 'PORT_A', 'ALARM_2', 'CREATION_1' from dual union all
     select 'NODE_C', 'PORT_C', 'ALARM_1', 'CREATION_4' from dual union all
     select 'NODE_C', 'PORT_C', 'ALARM_2', 'CREATION_4' from dual 
     )
select node_id, port_id, alarm_id, creation_time 
  from (select t.*, 
               count(case when alarm_id = 'ALARM_2' then 1 end) 
                   over (partition by node_id, creation_time) cnt
          from t )
  where cnt = 0



NODE_ID PORT_ID ALARM_ID CREATION_TIME
------- ------- -------- -------------
NODE_B  PORT_B  ALARM_3  CREATION_2
```

Comment: I don't understand. In the t table you use (select 'NODE_A', 'PORT_A', 'ALARM_1', 'CREATION_1') but I don't know before what is the result for NODE_A', 'PORT_A', 'ALARM_1', 'CREATION_1

Comment: These are example, test data, copied from your question and needed here to show that query works. You need only the part starting from `select ...`. Run main query on your data changing `T` to your table name and check results.